# Preventing direct file access in asp.net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a folder called PrivatePdf which is readable and writable where i stored the pdf file of the user. I would like to allow only the user itself to have access to the pdf file by pasting the link directly. eg: When other user paste the link abc.com/PrivatePdf/123.pdf into the browser, it will not show the pdf file.

Note: the PrivatePdf folder allows read/write and i do not wish to keep it into App_Data folder. The user authentication is based on asp.net identity

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Windows authentication (not likely), you could use filesystem-level permissions. Otherwise, I would recommend you setup an handler for all (or maybe just PDF) files in that folder and implement your own restriction logic.
To register an handler, you need to add something like this to a new web.config inside the folder:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <httpHandlers>
            <add verb="*" path="*.pdf" type="MyHandler, MyAssembly"/>
       </httpHandlers>
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

The handler must implement IHttpHandler and in its ProcessRequest method you need to check if the user is authenticated, by looking at HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated or HttpContext.User.Identity.Name and see if the user has valid access to the file pretended, which is available from HttpContext.Request properties.